# Store video files publicly accessible to other apps in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-gallery

This is the current code I have to store videos generated by my app on disk. I want this videos to be accessible by other apps like TikTok, WhatsApp and google Photos. I also want to create my own gallery inside my app. However, the files saved by approach below do not show up on TikTok.  They show up under Google photos Library\Movies folder, which users have to really dig deep to find.

How to make these files accessible to all apps? how can I write my own video gallery to just show files created by my app?

```
private void addVideoToGallery(File videoFile) {
        Uri uriSavedVideo;
        File createdvideo = null;
        ContentResolver resolver = activity.getContentResolver();

        String path = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        String videoFileName = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        ContentValues valuesvideos;
        valuesvideos = new ContentValues();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + File.pathSeparator + activity.getString(R.string.app_name));
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            Uri collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);
            uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(collection, valuesvideos);
        } else {
            String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES;
            createdvideo = new File(directory, videoFileName);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, videoFileName);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, videoFileName);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4");
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, createdvideo.getAbsolutePath());
            uriSavedVideo = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, valuesvideos);
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1);
        }

        ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
        try {
            pfd = resolver.openFileDescriptor(uriSavedVideo, "w");
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(videoFile);
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            pfd.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            valuesvideos.clear();
            valuesvideos.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            resolver.update(uriSavedVideo, valuesvideos, null, null);
        }
    }
```

This code cannot access the same files from my app using code below.

```
    private void getVids(){
    List<Video> videoList = new ArrayList<Video>();

    Uri collection;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL);
    } else {
        collection = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION,
            MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE
    };
    String selection = MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION +
            " >= ?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {
            String.valueOf(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES))};
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    try (Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(
            collection,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            sortOrder
    )) {
        // Cache column indices.
        int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID);
        int nameColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int durationColumn =
                cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        int sizeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.SIZE);

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            // Get values of columns for a given video.
            long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
            int duration = cursor.getInt(durationColumn);
            int size = cursor.getInt(sizeColumn);

            Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);

            // Stores column values and the contentUri in a local object
            // that represents the media file.
            videoList.add(new Video(contentUri, name, duration, size));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should specify the problems separately for the Android version of used devices. Your code threads Android versions different which is good. And if you only have problems on Q+ then post only that code.

Comment: Your app can query all its files by selecting for RELATIVE_PATH equal to Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + File.pathSeparator + activity.getString(R.string.app_name) .

Comment: Write also a little app which queries that relative path. Especially on Android 11 as Android 11 is very picky concerning the owner of files. If your testapp can list them then there is no reason other app can not.

Comment: Thanks, my phone is version 28. Why cant tiktok pickup the files?

Comment: Well ...who sais TikTok cant? TikTok doesn;t. Who knows why?  And... can your test app do it?

Comment: I have added code above, but the test app cannt see the files.

Comment: Why are you talking about a testapp if that code does not even work for your first app? Or do i understand not correct?

Comment: `This code cannot access the same files from` Access? What do you mean? That that code does not list/find your files ? Do not try to select on duration to begin with if you wanna check if your files can be listed/found. Do not even use thye DURATION column.

Comment: 'while (cursor.moveToNext())' has no values.

Comment: Ok its working. query filter was wrong. My bad. But first question still remains. Why cant TikTok pick up the files.

Comment: Sighh...I told you .. Now did you make another app to test if that can read/list the files of your first app?

Comment: The movies folder cannot be found, by youtube and tiktok. They only show vids from Camera app.